# Send ContactUs information to the id of website owner

Tags: asp.net, email

I am making a website in asp.net with c#.I want to send the contact us information to 
    email id.But it is giving exception that "failure sending email".I am writing the code.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        message.From = new MailAddress(Email.Text);//email is the sender email id

        message.To.Add(new MailAddress("myemail@gmail.com"));

        message.Subject = "feedback";

        message.Body = "Name: " + Comments.Text;  // enquiry or comment
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Host = "127.0.0.1";
        client.Port=42157;
        client.Send(message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        status.Text = "Send Email Failed.<br>" + ex.Message;
    }

  }
}


 Web config file
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp from="">
 <network host="127.0.0.1" port="49157" userName="" password="" defaultCrededentials>
  </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

Answer (score 0):

sending the email needs credentials and if you are using Exchange server, this credentials you should get it from the Email administrator.

if you want to send the email despite of using the exchange server credentials, you can use google or yahoo or live smtp

kindly, check this link for more information
[Sending Email using gmail smtp](http://www.emailarchitect.net/easendmail/kb/csharp.aspx?cat=2)

[Sending email using gmail or yahoo or live smtp](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/520998/Send-Email-from-Yahoo-GMail-Hotmail-Csharp)

hope that this will help you

regards

Comment: I am sending email to my email id only(recepient id) from contact us page.why it will need credentials?

Comment: because smtpClient is used to send e-mail to an SMTP server for delivery, check this link for more understanding of Smtp Client class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Okay,i am using localhost for this and i have mentioned the credentials in the web config file.